# Laravel 4 - Checks to see if post belongs to the user

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if you could give me a bit of advice / code for the following.

I have an authentication system, using the standard Laravel user authentication.

Once logged in, the user can add / edit blog posts.

This works perfect,and the url to edit is as follows

```
/blog/edit/3
```

Where 3 is the ID of the blog post.

The problem im seeing is that i log in and and manipulate the URL i can edit any blog post even if it doesnt belong to me.

Is there any way i can sort this so that only the people that add the blog post can edit the blog post?

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. My current preference is to use a custom filter:

```
Route::model('blog', 'Blog');
Route::get('/blog/edit/{blog}', ['as' => 'blog.edit', 'before' => 'auth.blog', 'uses' => 'BlogController@edit']);
```

Then in your filters file

```
Route::filter('auth.blog', function($route, $request)
{
    if ($route->parameter('blog')->user_id !== Auth::user()->id)
    {
        return Redirect::route('home')->with('error', 'sorry - you do not have access to that blog');
});
```

Comment: That makes sense ... I can understand that ... I just have one question, what is the $route, $request mean? and where is that coming from?

Comment: Big - they are passed in to the filters by Laravel - they are the route and request generated by the visit to the site.

Comment: Ohhh ok, that makes alot of sense ... Thank you once again for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, one more thing ... the parameter('blog') bit ... im guessing that has to be changed to suit my code, would that be Blog::find($id) ?

Comment: No - because you bind the Blog model to your route - so the blog model is passed into the filter.

Comment: Keep in mind: Route Model binding is a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a edit and update methods in your controller.

```
public function edit($id)
{
  $blog = Blog::find($id);

  if (Auth::user()->id !== $blog->user_id)
  {
    return Redirect::route('home')->withError("Un-Authorise access");
  }

}
```

Same thing for the update function.

```
public function update($id)
{
  $blog = Blog::find($id);

  if (Auth::user()->id !== $blog->user_id)
  {
    return Redirect::route('home')->withError("Un-Authorise access");
  }

}
```

Comment: This is the most simple way. I don't prefer this when you have many functions in the controller that needs auth.